# Lock screen never requires password - 16.04

Tags: security, lock-screen

My screen will dim and suspend normally but never requires a password when coming back on. I have attempted the shortcuts: Ctrl+Alt+l as well as Super+l with the same result; I have also tried activating the gnome-screensaver from the CLI, also with the same result.

After reading through several threads here, I replaced gnome-screensaver with XScreenSaver X11. This program allowed me to lock the screen but does not require a password when powering the laptop on from a complete shutdown.

I then used the CLI to purge XScreenSaver and reinstall gnome-screensaver, then checked for any software updates. I am still having the same problem.

This is my first question here so I apologize if I inadvertently violate decorum.

Comment: The box is checked to `Lock screen when screensaver is active` in your screen saver preferences I assume?

Comment: Yes. More specifically, the screen is set to turn off when inactive for 5 minutes; the lock is set to engage immediately when the screen turns off. In addition, there is a check in the box labeled "Require my password when waking from suspend"

Comment: I'm going to try running Ubuntu 17.04 from an installation USB on the same computer. If that resolves the issue, I will just upgrade the kernel. Either way, I will report back here the result.

Comment: Well, that didn't work.

Comment: Issue is resolved: I still don't know what caused it but, after upgrading to 17.10 (without a change in OP problem), I just reinstalled 16.04 and now the lock screen functions perfectly.